# replacing the process with file url instead of file upload in php

Tags: php

am uploading a Pdf file and passing it to getExtact function to extract pages from file which is being uploaded if any error in extraction we will send the file to decryptPDF function for which the input parameters are filename and filetempname for both the functions but here am using  a file upload process i want to use file url like www.domainname.com/docs/1.pdf so that all the functions which are written already can be used : Below is my code

//here for the above variable values are coming from uploaded file here i want to use file url and all the pdf are in my own server

```
   $FileName = $_FILES['inputfile']['name'];
        $TempFileName = $_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name']; $Folderpath='/home/domain/public_html/pdftest/temp';
            try {
                .
                GetExtract($TempFileName,$FileName); 
            } catch (Exception $e) {

                $responce = DecryptPDF($Folderpath,$Filename,$TempFileName);        
                if($responce == ''){
                    $Inputfile = $Folderpath.'/un_'.$Filename;

                    GetExtract($Inputfile,$FileName);
                }else{
                    echo $responce;         
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge,local server $PATH is "/var/www/".Try putting your inputfiles in that location.Then only you can access the files using url.

Comment: hi thank you..can u please elaborate what you mean,is any other way?

Comment: @user4022479: Try by changing '$Folderpath' from '/home/domain/public_html/pdftest/temp' to '/var/www/some_path/' and put all  your files ..